# WordPress dynamic paging - url conflict

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have downloaded theme which is static html & css template, now I'm trying to convert into wordpress dynamic template. the issue is that the static template is one page website and have some section within it. Scrolling to these section is done by jquery function that uses url to scroll to that specific section like this:

```
mysite.com/?page=about
```

so its conflict with main wordpress dynamic paging the website doesn't scroll to that specific section any more.

I've tried to change jquery code in my template but I couldn't fix it, is there a way to change the default wordpress setting in order to stop this conflict?

here the JS code :

```
(function(window, undefined) {
        "use strict";   
var Page    = (function() {

    var $container          = $( '#container' ),
        // the scroll container that wraps the articles
        $scroller           = $container.find( 'div.content-scroller' ),
        $menu               = $container.find( 'aside' ),
        // menu links
        $links              = $menu.find( 'nav > a' ),
        $articles           = $container.find( 'div.content-wrapper > article' ).not(".noscroll"),



        // button to scroll to the top of the page
        // only shown when screen size < 715
        $toTop              = $container.find( 'a.totop-link' ),
        // the browser nhistory object
        History             = window.History,
        // animation options
        animation           = { speed : 800, easing : 'easeInOutExpo' },
        // jScrollPane options
        scrollOptions       = { verticalGutter : 0, hideFocus : true },
        // init function
        init                = function() {

            // initialize the jScrollPane on both the menu and articles
            _initCustomScroll();
            // initialize some events
            _initEvents();
            // sets some css properties 
            _layout();
            // jumps to the respective chapter
            // according to the url
            _goto();

        },
        _initCustomScroll   = function() {


            // Only add custom scroll to articles if screen size > 715.
            // If not the articles will be expanded
            if( $(window).width() > 767 ) {

                $articles.jScrollPane( scrollOptions );

            }
            // add custom scroll to menu
            $menu.children( 'nav' ).jScrollPane( scrollOptions );

        },
        _goto               = function( chapter ) {

                // get the url from history state (e.g. chapter=3) and extract the chapter number
            var chapter     = chapter || History.getState().url.queryStringToJSON().page,
                isHome      = ( chapter === undefined ),
                // we will jump to the introduction chapter if theres no chapter
                $article    = $( chapter ? '#' + 'chapter' + chapter : '#' + 'introduction' );




                $('#link_introduction').removeClass('active');
                $('#link_about').removeClass('active');
                $('#link_skills').removeClass('active');
                $('#link_experience').removeClass('active');
                $('#link_education').removeClass('active');
                $('#link_portfolio').removeClass('active');
                $('#link_contact').removeClass('active');

                $('#link_'+chapter).addClass('active');

            if( $article.length ) {

                    // left / top of the element
                var left        = $article.position().left,
                    top         = $article.position().top,
                    // check if we are scrolling down or left
                    // is_v will be true when the screen size < 715
                    is_v        = ( $(document).height() - $(window).height() > 0 ),
                    // animation parameters:
                    // if vertically scrolling then the body will animate the scrollTop,
                    // otherwise the scroller (div.content-scroller) will animate the scrollLeft
                    param       = ( is_v ) ? { scrollTop : (isHome) ? top : top + $menu.outerHeight( true ) } : { scrollLeft : left },
                    $elScroller = ( is_v ) ? $( 'html, body' ) : $scroller;

                $elScroller.stop().animate( param, animation.speed, animation.easing, function() {

                    // active class for selected chapter
                    //$articles.removeClass( 'content-active' );
                    //$article.addClass( 'content-active' );


                } );

            }

        },
        _saveState          = function( chapter ) {

            // adds a new state to the history object
            // this will trigger the statechange on the window
            if( History.getState().url.queryStringToJSON().page !== chapter ) {

                History.pushState( null, null, '?page=' + chapter );

                $('#link_introduction').removeClass('active');
                $('#link_about').removeClass('active');
                $('#link_skills').removeClass('active');
                $('#link_experience').removeClass('active');
                $('#link_education').removeClass('active');
                $('#link_portfolio').removeClass('active');
                $('#link_contact').removeClass('active');

                $('#link_'+chapter).addClass('active');

            }

        },
        _layout             = function() {

            // control the overflow property of the scroller (div.content-scroller)
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();

            var isipad = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("ipad");
            if(isipad > -1)
            {
                //$('.totop-link').hide();
                switch( true ) {
                case ( windowWidth <= 768 ) : $scroller.scrollLeft( 0 ).css( 'overflow', 'visible' ); break;
                case ( windowWidth <= 1024 ): $scroller.css( 'overflow-x', 'hidden' ); break;
                case ( windowWidth > 1024 ) : $scroller.css( 'overflow', 'hidden' ); break;
                };
            }
            else
            {
                switch( true ) {
                case ( windowWidth <= 768 ) : $scroller.scrollLeft( 0 ).css( 'overflow', 'visible' ); break;
                case ( windowWidth <= 1024 ): $scroller.css( 'overflow-x', 'hidden' ); break;
                case ( windowWidth > 1024 ) : $scroller.css( 'overflow', 'hidden' ); break;
                };
            }

        },
        _initEvents         = function() {

            _initWindowEvents();
            _initMenuEvents();
            _initArticleEvents();

        },
        _initWindowEvents   = function() {

            $(window).on({

                // when resizing the window we need to reinitialize or destroy the jScrollPanes
                // depending on the screen size
                'smartresize' : function( event ) {

                    var isipad = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("ipad");
                    var ismobile =  navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("mobile");
                    if(isipad > -1 || ismobile > -1 )
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _layout();

                        $('article.content').not(".noscroll").each( function() {

                            var $article    = $(this),
                                aJSP        = $article.data( 'jsp' );

                            if( $(window).width() > 767 ) {

                                ( aJSP === undefined ) ? $article.jScrollPane( scrollOptions ) : aJSP.reinitialise();

                                _initArticleEvents();

                            }   
                            else {

                                // destroy article's custom scroll if screen size <= 715px
                                if( aJSP !== undefined )
                                    aJSP.destroy();

                                $container.off( 'click', 'article.content' );

                            }

                        });

                        var nJSP = $menu.children( 'nav' ).data( 'jsp' );
                        nJSP.reinitialise();

                        // jumps to the current chapter
                        _goto();
                    }

                },
                // triggered when the history state changes - jumps to the respective chapter
                'statechange' : function( event ) {

                    _goto();

                }
            });

        },
        _initMenuEvents     = function() {

            // when we click a menu link we check which chapter the link refers to,
            // and we save the state on the history obj.
            // the statechange of the window is then triggered and the page/scroller scrolls to the 
            // respective chapter's position
            $links.on( 'click', function( event ) {

                var href        = $(this).attr('href'),
                    chapter     = ( href.search(/chapter/) !== -1 ) ? href.substring(8) : 0;

                _saveState( chapter );
                if (href.indexOf("#") != -1) 
                    return false;
                else 
                    return true;



            });

            // scrolls to the top of the page.
            // this button will only be visible for screen size < 715
            $toTop.on( 'click', function( event ) {

                $( 'html, body' ).stop().animate( { scrollTop : 0 }, animation.speed, animation.easing );

                return false;

            });

        },
        _initArticleEvents  = function() {

            // when we click on an article we check which chapter the article refers to,
            // and we save the state on the history obj.
            // the statechange of the window is then triggered and the page/scroller scrolls to the 
            // respective chapter's position



                if($(window).width()>768)
                {
                    $container.on( 'click', 'article.content', function( event ) {

                        var id          = $(this).attr('id'),
                            chapter     = ( id.search(/chapter/) !== -1 ) ? id.substring(7) : 0;

                        _saveState( chapter );

                        //return false;

                    });
                }





        };

    return { init : init }; 

})();

Page.init();
```

})(window);

Comment: The issue is not WordPress, the issue is that your JS is not working so the site is behaving as such and trying to load a page rather than scroll to a section. If you want more help you really should paste in the js function.

Comment: You should use `mysite.com/#about` instead of using a query variable

Comment: @SimonPollard Edited , I've put the code.. any help ?

Comment: @Deepakjha I've tried and I'll will again.. but if any help another way please help